# How to implement a base component that preprocess all urls and let all other components extends it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When someone opens any url with my domain, I want to keep track of a query string variable(named var), so my idea is to make a parent Component that at componentWillMount, take the query string, and save it to a redux state variable, if that state variable is currently undefined.

For example, if someone comes to this url:

mydomain.com/anyurl/?var=abc

Now I will set the state variable to abc. And then when the viewer navigates to another page within my domain, the var in the query string can be dismissed, but we still keep track of the activity, even they go to mydomain.com/anyurl2 we still know this is from the one with var=abc.

Here is my approach:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { recordRefUrl } from '../actions/actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class BaseContainer extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.location.query.var && !this.props.urlRefParam) {
            this.props.dispatch(recordRefUrl(this.props.location.query.var ));
        }
    }
}

function select(state) {
    return {
        urlRefParam: state.urlRefParam,
    }
}

export default connect(select)(BaseContainer)
```

And then in all components(in the same root folder as BaseContainer), I will let them extends BaseContainer instead of Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import BaseContainer from './BaseContainer'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export default class HomePageHandler extends BaseContainer {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>hello</div>
        )
    }
}
```

The app.js I have is something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Router, useRouterHistory, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

//redux stuff
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import { createStore, renderDevTools } from './utils/devTools'

let appHistory = appHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({basename: '/'})

let store = createStore(CitySearchApp,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
)

let routes = (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="app">
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router history={appHistory} onUpdate={fireTracking}>
                    <Route name="main" component={AppHandler}>
                        <Route name="home" path="/" component={HomePageHandler}/>
                    </Route>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
            {renderDevTools(store)}
        </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
)

render(routes, document.body)
```

and the package.json looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.4.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.0",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.0.0",
    "react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dnd-touch-backend": "^0.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0",
    "react-flip-move": "^2.4.1",
    "react-ga": "2.1.2",
    "react-input-range": "^1.0.2",
    "react-mount": "^0.1.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.3",
    "redux": "^3.1.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "react-scroll":"^1.5.4",
    "url-parse": "^1.1.9"
  },
```

However this gives me error:

```
Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(BaseContainer)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(BaseContainer)".
```

If I changed my codes so that HomePageHandler extends Component directly, then it will work.

What is wrong with my codes? Thanks!

Comment: Does the root of your app contain the `Provider` component (somewhere at the top of the tree), like the error-message suggests?

Comment: @stinodes updated app.js - provider is indeed there.

Answer (score 0):

```
render(
    <Provider store={STORE}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={app}/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Can you post content of the entry point of your app. It should be something similar to above code.

Comment: You can keep your HomePageHandler extends Component and move the BaseContainer logics in AppHandler Component.

Comment: I'm not sure but it can be because you have not created constructor and called super(props) inside it. But it's better if you can avoid using class. There's a good article written on it by Eric Eliott [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/how-to-fix-the-es6-class-keyword-2d42bb3f4caf).